# Using manual buttons in table view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating a commenting application that displays a number of comments in a table view from an array. Users can like, dislike or flag comments. I have incorporated this in the application, however, whenever a user clicks like, dislike or flag, the first comment is always actioned.

This is the first couple of lines in my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
NSDictionary *myArray = [commentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
commentID = [myArray objectForKey:@"ID"];
```

I've tried to send the the commentID as the tag of the button, but I then realised that it was an ID that included many letters, e.g. 7c3769f28c9547f4b6889201a8c13f1e.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How are you calling that code?

Comment: Example: [newLikeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(likeButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: And where is `indexPath` from?

Comment: @trojanfoe "This is the first couple of lines in my cellForRowAtIndexPath:"

Comment: @SteveWilford I don't see the relationship between `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `likeButtonPressed:` (as just posted by the OP).

Comment: My presumption was that the code snippet in the question is part of the `cellForRowAtIndex:` method where he's also connecting the `newLikeButton` to `likeButtonPressed:`.

Comment: @SteveWilford Oh I don't know - not enough information, but I think you have supplied the correct solution anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way around this is to set the tag of the button as the `indexPath.row` of the cell when you create it.

Then in your `likeButtonPressed:` and other button handler methods you can use the button's tag to get the data from the correct index:

```
-(void)likeButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = sender;
    NSDictionary *commentData = commentArray[button.tag];
    // Do what you want with commentData here...
}
```

Comment: +1 Yes.  The OP needs to provide context to the controls within the cell, and this is one way of doing it.

Comment: I now have this in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

`[newLikeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(likeButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
newLikeButton.tag = indexPath.row;`

And in the action method:
`UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;`

I know that will return 0,1,2 etc, how did I get that to send the actual commentID?

Comment: See my edited answer, you'd just need to get the comment data from your `commentArray` that was used in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, presumably this is a `@property` or ivar in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I Had implemented the same concept in my app like this way,
Create a nsobject class,declare and implement buttons in that,the in your class cell for row method write like this way,
cell =(customCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell = [[DetailsRoomsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.buttonRoomType1.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
cell.button2.tag = indexPath.row+1;
[cell.buttonRoomType2 addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

cellForRowAtIndexPath Code

```
btnlike.tag = indexPath.row
[btnlike addTarget:self action:@selector(likeButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

likeButtonPressed Method

```
-(IBAction)likeButtonPressed:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"Button tag :%d",[sender tag]);
}
```